# Extent an interface

Tags: c#

I have an interface that implements an enumerator, something along the lines of

```
foreach(IClass i in collection)
{

}
```

I have no access to the code of IClass or collection because it is in a library I am building upon. Now I want to add properties to IClass. What I have been trying is

```
public class IClassExt : IClass 
{
    ... IClass properties
    ... additional properties
}
```

But now I can't figure out how to get an IClassExt when I call

```
 foreach(IClassExt i in collection)
{
}
```

I tried a cast from IClass to IClassExt but that is both not allowed and even if it worked it would be too time consuming if I had to do it each time I used the loop. I need to be able to implement all my IClass as IClassExt once and make my collection a  IClassExt  collection instead of an IClass collection.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "time consuming"? How time consuming is it?

Comment: The interface `IClass` doesn't implement an enumerator if you're doing `foreach(IClass i in collection)`. Whatever type `collection` is, it implements `IEnumerable<IClass>`

Comment: @Thomas Weller: I was thinking of trying something like foreach(IClass i in collection){ IclassExt = (IClassExt) i  ... and then do something with i}. But that would mean I had to assign the additional properties each time I used the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the OfType<> Linq extension method to get the instances of `IClassExt` in `collection`. This allows for both `IClass` and `IClassExt` instances to reside in the same collection.

Example class and interface setups

```
public interface IClass{
    string ClassName {get;set;}
    bool IsValid {get;set;}
}
public interface IClassExt:IClass{
    string SuperiorClassName {get;set;}
}
public class Foo: IClass{
    public string ClassName {get;set;}
    public bool IsValid {get;set;}
}
public class Bar: IClassExt{
    public string ClassName {get;set;}
    public bool IsValid {get;set;}
    public string SuperiorClassName {get;set;}  
}
```

Usage:

```
var collection = new IClass[]{new Foo{ClassName = "MyFooClass", IsValid=true}, new Bar{ClassName="MyBarClass", IsValid=false, SuperiorClassName = "MySuperiorFooBarClass"}};
foreach (IClassExt classExt in collection.OfType<IClassExt>()){
    //Do something really cool here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```
var iClassCollection = collection.Select(c=> (ICollectionExt)c).ToList();

foreach(IClassExt i in iClassCollection)
{
   // ... 
}
```

Comment: This makes the assumption that all instances in `collection` are of type `ICollectionExt`.

Answer (score 0):

You state the following:

> I have no access to the code of IClass or collection because it is in a library I am building upon.

But then:

> I need to be able to implement all my IClass as IClassExt once and make my collection a IClassExt collection instead of an IClass collection.

If you don't have the source for the collection, then you can't MAKE it a collection of IClassExt.  It will always be a collection of IClass, but COULD contain IClassExt, the same way a List can contain a string (or anything else inheriting from object).  Making the assumption that everything in your collection is an IClassExt is unsafe however, because, while you can guarantee that every IClassExt is also an IClass, you cannot guarantee that every IClass is an IClassExt, and even if you personally wrote all your code that way, you can't be sure the next person to work on your code won't decide to throw some other IClass objects into the collection.  This means that, to code safely, you must test that the object in the collection is an IClassExt.

Using the "OfType" extension method referenced in the other answer is a good way to ensure safety when accessing the collection.  Another possibility would be to use a wrapper class to insert and access the collection.

The best option, in my opinion, would simply be to create your own collection of IClassExt and use that instead.  The work involved in changing all of your code to use IClassExt instead of IClass was something that needed to be addressed when the application was architected.